# Browser's JavaScript execution using JMeter

Tags: javascript, scripting, jmeter

There is one scenario in which if JavaScript will be allowed to execute in browser then only complete page will be loaded otherwise it will not load the page.

Now I want to record and replay the same scenarios using JMeter.

Could anyone please suggests me how can I replicate the same scenarios using JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter only records the requests thats been sent to server. It will not record javascript that happens in browser/client side. Do not compare Jmeter with automation recording tool.

To be more precise, it records only the communication between client and server and it supports the following protocols

```
Web: HTTP, HTTPS sites 'web 1.0' web 2.0 (ajax, flex and flex-ws-amf)
Web Services: SOAP / XML-RPC.
Database via JDBC drivers.
Directory: LDAP.
Messaging Oriented service via JMS.
Service: POP3, IMAP, SMTP.
FTP Service.
```